# Ajax POST 413 Payload Too Large NodeJs + Express 4>

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My Ajax POST throwing an error 413 Payload Too Large. I tried out the following solution in my nodejs code:

```
"use strict";
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');  
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

var workspace = (app, dbconn)=>{
  app.use( bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}) );
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true,
  parameterLimit:50000
  }));
}
```

But this is still throwing the error.

My ajax call is as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/private/save_ws",
    type: 'post',
    headers: {'x-secure':_user_token, 'x-user':_user_name},
    contentType: 'application/json',       
    dataType: 'json',            
    data: widget_data
}).done(function(response){
    console.log('success');
}).fail(function(data){
    console.log('FAILED! ERROR: ');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In versions of Express > 4, `body-parser` is included in the Express library. You need to make changes like the below.

Instead of this:

```
app.use( bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}) );  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true,  
    parameterLimit:50000
}));
```

Do this:

```
app.use( express.json({limit: '50mb'}) );  
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true,  
    parameterLimit:50000
}));
```